# Show that if $P(A\mid B) = P(A\mid B^c)$, $0 < P(B) < 1$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

I looking for confirmation, or not, that I am on the correct track with the following proof.

Show that if $P(A\mid B) = P(A\mid B^c), 0 < P(B) < 1$, then $A$ and $B$ are independent?

**Attempt**

By way of contradiction assume that $A$ and $B$ are not independent. Then,
\begin{align*}
P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid B^c)&\Rightarrow\dfrac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B^c\cap A)}{P(A)}\quad\text{by definition}\\
&\Rightarrow P(B\cap A)= P(B^{c}\cap A)
\end{align*}
But this contradicts $0 < P(B) < 1$. Thus, $A$ and $B$ must be independent.

Thank you in advance for any helpful feedback. Cheers.

Comment: Check the definition of conditional probability that you are using. Is it exactly the same as in your book?

Comment: You need $\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(B\cap A)}{\Pr(B)}$, not $\dfrac{\Pr(B\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}$. $\qquad$

Comment: How does your conclusion about equality of probabilities of two intersections contradict $0<P(B)<1$? You completely lost me there. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align}
P(A)
& = P(A \mid B)\cdot P(B)+P(A \mid B^{\complement})\cdot P(B^{\complement}) \\
& = P(A \mid B) \cdot P(B)+P(A \mid B)\cdot P(B^{\complement}) \\
& = P(A \mid B) \cdot \big(P(B)+P(B^{\complement})\big) \\
& = P(A \mid B) \cdot 1.
\end{align}

This implies $P(A)=P(A|B)$

Comment: excellent solution more concise than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition on condition probability is wrong. Here is a correct one:
$P(A|B)= \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(B)}$

Here is the proof of the proposition:

$P(A) = P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^{c})) =  P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^{c}) $

Since $P(A|B) = P(A|B^c) \implies P(A \cap B) P(B^c) = P(A \cap B^c) P(B)$

$P(A)P(B) = P(A \cap B) P(B) + P(A \cap B^{c}) P(B) =\\\ P(A \cap B) P(B) + P(A \cap B) P(B^c) =  P(A \cap B) (P(B) +  P(B^c)) =P(A \cap B)  $

So $A,B$ are independent.

I have not yet thought a proof by contradiction but this proof is really concise.